# Is every literal an expression?

Tags: language-agnostic, expression, literals

Let's begin with some definitions:

- An `expression` is a construct that produces (returns) a value.
- A `literal` is a notation for representing a fixed value.

I could assume the literal is a expression that returns exactly one value. E.g. the literal `1` is an expression that returns the value 1.

Is there anything wrong in my approach or does being a literal always imply being an expression?

Thank you for clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a rigid definition of "literal". OTOH, I think you'd be hard-pressed to find anything commonly considered a literal that isn't a valid expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you account for language-specific exceptions (Python docstrings, C macros, etc.), you are correct. In general, every literal is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

That's my understanding.  To think of it another way:

`4-3` is one way of expressing `1`

`1` is another way of expressing `1`

They are both expressions, because they both express a value (`1`). But `1` is also a literal - because it's *literally* `1`.